# Constant group schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $G$ be any group. $R$ is a $Z$-module. Let $G_{SpecR}=\amalg_{g\in G}SpecR$. I see that $G_{SpecR}\times_{SpecZ}G_{Spec R} $ is isomorphic with $\amalg_{g,g^{'}\in G}SpecR$ from the note "finite group scheme".My question is

1)Why they are isomorphic ? What is the isomorphic map?

2)Since they are isomorphic ,I guess  that the elements of $G_{SpecR}\times_{SpecZ}G_{Spec R} $  look like $"a\times a"$ .Is it true?
If it is ture,why the elements are not $"a\times b"$?

Comment: Let's take $G=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ and $R=k[x]$. Then $\mathbb A^3\times \mathbb A^3\cong \mathbb A^6$, and not $\mathbb A^9$.

Comment: @danneks First,how to prove$\amalg_{g\in G}A^{1}$ is isomorphic $A^{3}$? Then how to prove in the general condition?

Comment: Sorry, it seemed to me that you wrote $\prod$, not $\amalg$. Then the counterexample is: take $G$ to be the trivial group and $R=k[t]$. Your statement says that $\mathbb A^1\times\mathbb A^1\cong\mathbb A^1$.